# nvolgv32.dll - glDrawElements trouble

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

At this moment Im coding a graphic app using OpenGL and Im drawing obj files using glDrawElements. I've a **Nvidia GeForce GT 740m**

The trouble is this : **First-chance exception at 0x68FCF460 (nvoglv32.dll) in demo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.** and I dont know how can I fix this.

These are my buffers initialization

```
    // <-- VBOs IBO VAO creation --> //

    glGenBuffers(3, obj_vbo);
    glGenBuffers(1, &obj_ibo);
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &obj_vao);

    // <-- IBO --> //

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj_ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj_triangles.size() * sizeof(GLushort), obj_triangles.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL);

    // <-- VAO --> //

    glBindVertexArray(obj_vao);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_LAYOUT);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj_vbo[VERTEX_LAYOUT]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj_vertices.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), obj_vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_LAYOUT, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, (GLubyte *) NULL);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_LAYOUT);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(NORMAL_LAYOUT);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj_vbo[NORMAL_LAYOUT]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj_normals.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), obj_normals.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(NORMAL_LAYOUT, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, (GLubyte *) NULL);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(NORMAL_LAYOUT);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(TEXTURE_LAYOUT);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj_vbo[TEXTURE_LAYOUT]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj_textures.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), obj_textures.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(TEXTURE_LAYOUT, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, (GLubyte *) NULL);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(TEXTURE_LAYOUT);

    glBindVertexArray(NULL);

    // <-- Save and calculate stuffs . . . --> //

    obj_triangles_size = (GLuint) obj_triangles.size();
```

And this is the draw method, where VERTEX_LAYOUT = 0, NORMAL_LAYOUT = 1, TEXTURE_LAYOUT = 2

```
    glBindVertexArray(obj_vao);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_LAYOUT);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(NORMAL_LAYOUT);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(TEXTURE_LAYOUT);

            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj_ibo);
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, obj_triangles_size, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(TEXTURE_LAYOUT);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(NORMAL_LAYOUT);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_LAYOUT);

    glBindVertexArray(NULL);
```

If I use the option (AUTO-SELECT) on my **nvidia panel / manage 3D** settings app renders good but when I switch that option to **High-performance NVIDIA processor** it gives this problem.

Comment: Stop enabling and disabling vertex attrib arrays for one thing. VAOs keep track of those states, the very act of binding `obj_vao` sets all that up, you are just doing some redundant stuff here that you should have done when you first setup your VAO (namely, enable the attribute arrays and ***do not*** disable them during initialization and then remove all the code that enables/disables them when you draw).

Comment: Hello Andon, thanks for your answer I tried that before this and it doesnt work. =/

Comment: VAOs also store the thing bound to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, so move the code that initializes your IBO until after you have a VAO created and then do not unbind the IBO. Then you will not have to bind the VAO before calling `glDrawElements (...)`. Overall, you are not using VAOs the way they were designed. It looks like you just tacked them on after the fact :-\

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: See my "answer" for an example. This is not going to solve your actual problem, but I was not able to explain how you were misusing VAOs in comments.

Comment: I don't think we're seeing the problem that causes the crash, but my best guess is that the sizes of some of your buffers are incorrect. For this to work cleanly, both `obj_vertices.size()` and `obj_normals.size()` need to be 3 times `obj_triangles_size`, `obj_textures.size()` needs to be 2 times `obj_triangles_size`, and `obj_triangles.size()` needs to be equal to `obj_triangles_size`. Can you double check that all these conditions are met?

Comment: BTW, this is not a correctness issue, but just makes the code hard to read: Some of your argument values are not really the right type. You pass `NULL` for `GLuint` arguments, and `GL_FALSE` for `GLsizei` parameters. And please listen to @AndonM.Coleman about how to use VAOs. ;)

Comment: All my buffers have correct dimensions @RetoKoradi, normals.size() / 3 = textures.size() / 2 = vertices.size() / 3, that isnt the problem because when I render my scene without using my video card I mean (auto select mode and no high graphic processor mode) it renders very good... I fixed VAO structure and the problem stills, I think it is a problem of interaction among NVIDIA and OpenGL.

Answer (score 3):

## Disclaimer:

#### This is not an answer, but explaining this in comments would be impossible.

---

Here is how VAOs are intended to be used, they actually track most of the states you are redundantly changing every time you draw.

#### Initialization:

```
// <-- VBOs IBO VAO creation --> //

glGenBuffers(3, obj_vbo);
glGenBuffers(1, &obj_ibo);
glGenVertexArrays(1, &obj_vao);

// <-- VAO --> //

glBindVertexArray(obj_vao);

    // <-- IBO (moved) --> //

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj_ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj_triangles.size() * sizeof(GLushort), obj_triangles.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    // glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL); -- REMOVE

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_LAYOUT);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj_vbo[VERTEX_LAYOUT]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj_vertices.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), obj_vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_LAYOUT, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, (GLubyte *) NULL);
    //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL);        -- REMOVE
    //glDisableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_LAYOUT);  -- REMOVE

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(NORMAL_LAYOUT);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj_vbo[NORMAL_LAYOUT]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj_normals.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), obj_normals.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(NORMAL_LAYOUT, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, (GLubyte *) NULL);
    //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL);        -- REMOVE
    ///glDisableVertexAttribArray(NORMAL_LAYOUT); -- REMOVE

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(TEXTURE_LAYOUT);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj_vbo[TEXTURE_LAYOUT]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj_textures.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), obj_textures.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(TEXTURE_LAYOUT, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, (GLubyte *) NULL);
    //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL);        -- REMOVE
    //glDisableVertexAttribArray(TEXTURE_LAYOUT); -- REMOVE

glBindVertexArray(NULL);

// <-- Save and calculate stuffs . . . --> //

obj_triangles_size = (GLuint) obj_triangles.size();
```

#### Drawing:

```
glBindVertexArray(obj_vao);

    //glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_LAYOUT);  -- REMOVE
    //glEnableVertexAttribArray(NORMAL_LAYOUT);  -- REMOVE
    //glEnableVertexAttribArray(TEXTURE_LAYOUT); -- REMOVE

        //glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj_ibo); -- REMOVE
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, obj_triangles_size, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);
        //glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL);    -- REMOVE

    //glDisableVertexAttribArray(TEXTURE_LAYOUT); -- REMOVE
    //glDisableVertexAttribArray(NORMAL_LAYOUT);  -- REMOVE
    //glDisableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_LAYOUT);  -- REMOVE

glBindVertexArray(NULL);
```

Comment: Okay I see, I tried that but this trouble looks like that I've a 'limit' of elements that I can draw in glDrawElements, because Im rendering a grid of 40x40 vertices and it draws perfectly. (Im doing this before draw obj) with this example that you gave me.

Comment: There is no clear limit to the number of elements you can draw. About the only one that comes to mind immediately is a 4 GiB (32-bit) limit to the address space of buffer objects. That would be 1-2 billion elements in your element buffer, though the hardware would have some other limitation before you hit that point no doubt. `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` lets you identify 65k unique vertices, but does not impose any limitation on the size of your elements array (you could have vertex #256 appear 1 million times if you wanted).

Comment: Just one addition: The use of `NULL` should be reserved to be used with pointers. In C it doesn't make a difference, but C++ would give you nasty compilation warnings (or errors if you're enabling warning-to-error compiler flags as I do).